# Failed to extract object tree for large model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

everyone!

We'd like to extract an object tree and properties for a large model.

For that need, we tried to use the following queries: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/URN/metadata/GUID
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/URN/metadata/GUID/properties

After 2 hours delay, they are failed.

We found that we can work with `Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase` for getting the properties by dbId. This solution solves the issue of working with properties.

But we still have a problem with the object tree. We have not found a solution to combine data and get the same output as `GET :urn/metadata/:guid` returns?

Does someone know how we can reproduce the object tree from source files? Maybe there is some resource file that describes an object tree?

p.s. We use Node.js for the work

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force the request through by turning on `x-ads-force` in your request headers - see details [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-GET/#headers)

If that still fails send over (in our separate mail thread) the URN of the model so we can look into it.